# Getting file owner name without domain path

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to obtain the file owner without it being displayed in a DOMAIN/USERNAME format.

```
 Get-ChildItem T:\file\ -Recurse| Where { 
 $_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | select  @{Name='Date Modified'; Expression=
{$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}},  @{Name='Owner';E=
{$_.GetAccessControl().Owner}}, FullName
```

the owner output is this:

> 1stserver\username

Is there anyway I can get it to just this?:

> username

I am essentially trying to remove the domain name/server name from the file path and just display the username alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Get-ChildItem T:\file\ -Recurse| Where { 
 $_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | select  @{Name='Date Modified'; Expression=
{$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}},  @{Name='Owner';E=
{(($_.GetAccessControl().Owner.Split('\'))[1])}}, FullName
```

Using your code, we simply split the 'domain\user' by the separator '\' and then take the 1nth element (which is the user)

Comment: Second element, actually, as PowerShell uses zero-origin for arrays. My first inclination would have been to use `[-1]` instead, as that says "take the last element, regardless of how many happen to be in the array".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin if your domain name or user name have a backslash in them you've got bigger problems.

Comment: if it would've been the first element, i'd have said 0th since as you say, they are zero-based arrays.  This is a heavily typed object for a Windows Security descriptor, this value is always presented in this format.

Comment: @ConnorLSW - Definitely true, that - but who knows what Microsoft - or any other network OS provider - might do in the future?

Comment: If history is any indicator of the future, the Microsoft Security Descriptor has looked identical (as far as the DACL goes) since at least Windows NT and possibly before.

Comment: @thepip3r Hi there, thank you for your response, however; the solution does not appear to work. I ran  the following code:                            
          Get-ChildItem 
         T:\'IT Shared'\'#Chicago Desktop' -Recurse| Where 
         {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | select  @{Name='Date Modified'; 
         Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}},  
        @{Name='Owner';E={(($_.GetAccessControl().Owner -split '\')[1])}}, 
         FullName

Comment: Try the modification above.  For some reason, PowerShell can be finicky about whether it accepts the -split operator or you have to use the .split() method.  I've tested the above code to actually work using the .Split() method.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @thepip3r It Worked! Thank you!

Comment: I think `-split` may use a regexp, in which case it should work if you use `-split "\\"` instead - might be worth a try; it's certainly a common mistake.

Comment: The split operator does NOT use regex.  Now you can force it to if you want using the OPTIONS flag but it does not by default:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split